# Check if a value exists in array (Laravel or Php)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have this array:

```
$list_desings_ids = array('hc1wXBL7zCsdfMu','dhdsfHddfD','otheridshere');
```

With a die() + var_dump() this array return me:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "hc1wXBL7zCsdfMu"
  1 => "dhdsfHddfD"
  2 => "otheridshere"
]
```

I want check if a design_id exists in $list_desings_ids array.

For example:

```
foreach($general_list_designs as $key_design=>$design) {
    #$desing->desing_id return me for example: hc1wXBL7zCsdfMu
    if(array_key_exists($design->design_id, $list_desings_ids))
    $final_designs[] = $design;
}
```

But this not works to me, what is the correct way?

Comment: use in_array() function instead of array_key_exists ...because your $list_designs_ids array is not declared as key and value pair as per your description.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

instead `array_key_exists` you just type `in_array` this will solve your issue
because if you dump your this array

```
$list_desings_ids = array('hc1wXBL7zCsdfMu','dhdsfHddfD','otheridshere');
```

output will be,

```
array(
   0 => hc1wXBL7zCsdfMu,
   1 => dhdsfHddfD,
   2 => otheridshere
)
```

so your code `array_key_exists` will not work, because here in keys `0,1,2` exists, So, you want to check values,so for values, just do this `in_array` it will search for your desire value in your mentioned/created array

Answer (score 63):

You can use `in_array` for this.

Try

```
$design_id = 'hc1wXBL7zCsdfMu';
$list_desings_ids = array('hc1wXBL7zCsdfMu','dhdsfHddfD','otheridshere');

if(in_array($design_id, $list_desings_ids))
{
  echo "Yes, design_id: $design_id exits in array";

}
```

Answer (score 15):

you need to change only your condition replace with that code

```
if(in_array($design->design_id, $list_desings_ids))
```

Answer (score 8):

Your array not have key .
try this

```
foreach($general_list_designs as $key_design=>$design) {
       #$desing->desing_id return me for example: hc1wXBL7zCsdfMu
       if(in_array($design->design_id, $list_desings_ids))
       $final_designs[] = $design;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
```

First import above class then write below code

```
 $list = new Collection(['hc1wXBL7zCsdfMu', 'dhdsfHddfD', 'otheridshere']);
            $id = 'hc1wXBL7zCsdfMu';
            if ($list->contains($id)) {
                //yes: $id exits in array
            }
```