# How to validate a query string of multiple values concatenated in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I know how to validate a query string with a single value in this way,

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'category' => 'sometimes|nullable',
    'type' => [
        'required',
        Rule::in($this->propertyConfig['property_types']),
    ],
])->validate();
```

But what if I have a query string like this:

```
types=aa,bb,cc
```

I need to validate if **aa**, **bb** and **cc** are all in the array *$types*. How can I do that by using Laravel Validator?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35147366/check-if-a-value-exits-in-array-laravel-or-php/35147443

Answer (score 1):

```
$types = ['aa' , 'bb', 'cc'];
foreach($request->types as $type) {
    if(in_array($type, $types) {
        $flag = true;
    }
    else {
        $flag = false;
    }
}
```

Check flag variable after this code for your validation

Answer (score 0):

```
@php 
$ischeck = in_array($myvalue, explode(',', $myarray)) 
@endphp
```

Comment: I mean how to do this by using the Laravel validation framework.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36413073/how-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-an-array-in-laravel-validation